# Problem 12.65 - Griffiths Electrodynamics 4.ed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity

I'm working on this problem from Griffiths (specifically part b), where we have to show that a current square loop (side $l$) with uniform line charge density $\lambda$, carries an electric dipole moment from the point of view of a system $S'$. In this case, $S'$ is an infinite
uniform surface current (with surface charge $\sigma$ and moving in x-direction with speed $v$). The line charge has the same velocity on the square loop.

So, my question is about his answer, why does the back side have a positive charge as the solutions manual said?

Thanks for reading.

[image]